# Jmeter - How to fail the http request with certain message into the response using JSR223 Assertion

Tags: jmeter

While testing my API, and When something is wrong in the request I got messages like:

```
{
    "errorTimeStamp": "2021-10-21T14:08:11.7298099+02:00",
    "errorMessage": "Ticket with id 0 not found",
    "errorCode": 1001,
    "hasError": true
}
```

How to mark the httpRequest as failed(red into View Results Tree) based on: `"hasError": true`

I prefer to use JSR223 Assertion sampler, so later I can extend and include other matchers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
def hasError = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).hasError

if (hasError) {
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('Response data has error')
}
```

should do the trick for you

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) (`prev`) documentation
- [AssertionResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/assertions/AssertionResult.html) documentation
- [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)